# Prepared statement when only read

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there a point to use prepared statement when you just want to select all rows in a table? There are notning to bind compared if you used `WHERE name = ?` in the query.

```
$stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY name");
```

Is it better to use the MySQLi without Prepared Statements like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY name";
```

Comment: if there are no user supplied variables ( to be bound ) then no - just use `query`

Comment: If there is no user input I wouldn't mind

Comment: Preparing statements are only really useful to store the query in the db engine for quicker repeat queries. Since you're neither doing that nor using parameterized queries (where you store the query and submit the data separate) there is no reason to prepare the query first. just do a normal `$db->query('select...')`

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements are preferable to plain SQL queries when you are using parameters to dynamically generate the query. In your example, your SQL contains no variables, so using a plain query or prepared statement are functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

## Prepared Statements

To answer your question directly, no. And in many languages the prepared statement library wouldn't even work with a query like that due to the method signatures of that library.  I am going to give a background of prepare statements and database management systems because they are both essential to understanding the efficiencies generated by prepared statements.

#### Queries and Database's

When you execute a statement in any database management systems you trigger an execution of steps.  At a very high level the database management system does the following things.

1. Query is received by the DBMS
2. SQL is interpreted
3. Query parsing
4. Query optimization
5. Resultset returned

#### Prepared Statements and Database's

A prepared statement is similar to any other SQL query issued to a database management system except with a few caveats.

First, a prepared statement template (without parametic values) is sent to the database management system from the application.  After interpreting the SQL the database system then begins query parsing and query optimization where it validates the syntax and semantics, and begins the process of finding the best query plan, respectively.

A query plan is a set of executions used to run the supplied query. In most cases a query can have multiple query planes.  It is part of the database management system to pick the most efficient plane.

Query optimizer continues to generate a variety of query plans and assigned then a cost and a value.

This process so far is mostly the same for both prepared statements and regular statements.

So to understand why your query would not benefit from being a prepared statement (besides the fact that prepared statements are defined as necessarily having parameters), let's take a closer look into the prepared statement optimization.

#### Optimizing

We stayed before that the query optimizer picks from a list of query plans for the most efficient one.  However, we didn't discuss how it actually does this.  For a non parametic statement the optimizer assign each plan a scalar cost value.

However, for a parametic query the optimizer associates each query plant to a function that maps multi dimensional parameter space to cost space, respectively.  Basic to get all optimal queries for any given input.

This is a costly process, however on successive runs is very quick because the answer is known instead of calculates.
.